# Single-row subquery returns more than one row in snowflake

Tags: sql, join, types, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

This is the error that I get while running the following snowflake code.
I am aware that it is because of the TO_VARCHAR function is not for a whole table column..any idea on how to do workaround and have it applied to the whole column?

```
SELECT sv.SKU
       , li.price
       , li.cost_price
       , pc.product_description
FROM raw.stitch_heroku.spree_line_items as li 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
                 FROM raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants 
                 WHERE LENGTH(raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants.SKU) Between 4 and 5) as sv
ON li.variant_id = sv.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_description
                  , TO_VARCHAR(analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_ID) 
           FROM analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category) as pc
ON (SELECT TO_VARCHAR(analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_ID) 
    FROM analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category) = sv.id
GROUP BY  sv.SKU,li.price,li.cost_price,pc.product_description
```

I have to change the data type of the table called `analytics.dbt_lcasucci.products` from int to varchar, since without that the join will not recognize those fields and will just print null values even if the actual content of the cells would be matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong subquery in a ON clause  ..

```
SELECT sv.SKU
    , li.price
    , li.cost_price
    , pc.product_description
FROM raw.stitch_heroku.spree_line_items as li 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants 
    WHERE LENGTH(raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants.SKU) Between 4 and 5
) as sv ON li.variant_id = sv.id
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_description
    , TO_VARCHAR(analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_ID) my_key
    FROM analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category 
    ) as pc  ON pc.my_key = sv.id
```

and not having aggreagtion function  .. you don't need  group by  ..eventually use distinct if you don't want duplicated  rows

```
ON (SELECT TO_VARCHAR(analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_ID) 
    FROM analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category) = sv.id
```

Comment: Thanks! Which subquery is wrong? I am not sure which one of the 2 you are talking about.

Comment: answer  updated .. adding the ON clause that seems wrong to me

Comment: don't you have to specifiy on which key you are joinin on?

Comment: answer  updated ..  adding a (hope) clear key for join

Comment: The query works this way. However, the output is the same as if I do not add an TO VARCHAR...one of the column has only null values. I am afraid it is not picking up the transformation

Comment: i don't understant  ..  your question si not about an error for "Single-row subquery returns more than one row" ... ????

Comment: Correct. However, the only reason why I have been adding the to varchar to that whole script was to convert the data type from int to varchar. I asked a question about why I was getting that single row subquery, but I guess varchar is not supporting the transformation of a whole column

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the multiple values expression `TO_VARCHAR(analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_ID)` into a single value expression.

Use **any** aggregation function, like `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`, `SUM()`, etc.

For example, you can use `MAX(TO_VARCHAR(analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_ID))` as in:

```
SELECT
  sv.SKU,
  li.price, 
  li.cost_price,
  pc.product_description
FROM raw.stitch_heroku.spree_line_items as li 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT * 
  FROM raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants 
  WHERE LENGTH(raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants.SKU) Between 4 and 5
) as sv ON li.variant_id = sv.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_description,
    TO_VARCHAR(analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_ID) 
  FROM analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category
) as pc ON (
    SELECT MAX(TO_VARCHAR(analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_ID))
    FROM analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category
  ) = sv.id
GROUP BY sv.SKU, li.price, li.cost_price, pc.product_description
```

Comment: Thanks! However, my goal is to transform the whole column from int to varchar to pick up the , so a single value would not accomplish what I am trying to do...I am trying to join any values in that column to all the values of the table called sv. Makes sense?